# How to retrieve data from serialized jQuery string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

How to retrieve data when post using AJAX my function is that

```
jQuery("#wp_pass_reset").submit(function() {

var url = document.getElementById('imgurl').innerHTML;
var url2 = document.getElementById('adminurl').innerHTML;           

jQuery('#result').html('<span class="loading"><img src="' + url + '/img/load.gif" /></span>').fadeIn();
    var input_data = jQuery('#wp_pass_reset').serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url2 + 'admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
            action: 'resetpass_process',
            value: input_data,
        },
        success: function(msg){
            jQuery('.loading').remove();
              jQuery('<div>').html(msg).appendTo('div#result').hide().fadeIn('slow');
}
});
return false;

});
```

This is the form:

```
<form class="user_form" id="wp_pass_reset" action="" method="post" name="wp_pass_reset">
    <h1>
        Enter Your Email or Username
    </h1>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="user_input" value=""><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="tg_pwd_reset"> 
    <a class="close">X</a> 
    <input type="hidden" name="tg_pwd_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce("> 
    <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" class="reset_password btn" name="submit" value="Reset Password">
</form>
```

When I retrieve data using `$_POST['value']` all of my data show but when I use `$_POST['user_input']` an error happens.

What can I do?

Comment: I can't see user_input anywhere in your code

Comment: user_input is my form field name

Comment: use `print_r($_POST)` to see what is inside the `$_POST` array

Comment: `data: jQuery('#wp_pass_reset').serialize() + "&action=resetpass_process",` Or maybe you are looking for `.serializeArray()` instead

Comment: this form data get with using jquery function serialize

Comment: I tink you should use `$_POST['value']['user_input'];`

Comment: thanks dear Wolff your suggestion work

Comment: More obvious question is why the hell are you serialising a standard text string just do as both answers below suggest

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are submitting form by ajax then you have to pass it in `data` like,

```
 data: {
       action: 'resetpass_process',
       value: input_data,
       user_input : $('input[name="user_input"]').val(),
       // add more parmeters which you need
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

Add user_input from your form field name to data object:

```
...
data: {
    action: 'resetpass_process',
    value: input_data,
    user_input: $('input[name="user_input"]').val()
},
...
```